# Should the access and refresh token have the same payload?

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt, authorization

I'm creating and application with Laravel and NextJs and I'm developing the authentication and authorization with JWT (https://github.com/PHP-Open-Source-Saver/jwt-auth) but I have some doubts.

The login method performs:

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request): AuthResource | \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
    {
        $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
        $token = auth()->attempt($credentials, true);

        if (!$token) {
            return AuthResource::errors(
                ['auth.credentials.failed' => trans('auth.failed')]
            );
        }

        $jwt = "Bearer {$token}";
        $user = $request->user();
        $refreshToken =  $this->setJWTCookie('access_token', $jwt, config('app.jwt_cookie_minutes'));
        $accessToken =  $this->setJWTCookie('refresh_token', $jwt, config('app.jwt_cookie_minutes'), '/refresh');

        return AuthResource::make([
            'user' => [
                'id' => $user->id,
                'first_name' => $user->first_name,
                'last_name' => $user->last_name,
                'user_name' => $user->full_name,
                'email' => $user->email
            ]
        ])->response()->withCookie($refreshToken)->withCookie($accessToken);
    }
```

Here I return two cookies (httponly), one for refresh token (expires in one day) and another for access token (expires in two hours) but my doubts are:

1. Both token should have the same claims and data? or only the refresh token should have the important data?
2. Refresh token is valid only for /refresh path, so when the access token expires I should call /refresh to send the refresh token and generate a new access and refresh token. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh tokens are not described by the JWT RFC. So you can do it on your own way. For example you may use OAuth2 RFC for the [refresh tokens](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.5).

1. Refresh token contain data to able get new access token
2. Yes

Comment: And access token has some data?

Comment: @JuanPabloB set any data you need for that token. You can create variety tokens for your needs.